# Headset Microphone issues in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

I have Kubuntu 20.04 on my fairly new Dell XPS 13. When I start the computer, by default I am seeing 2 microphones in Kubuntu Audio settings. (At this point there is no headset connected, I confirmed that in the output devices also!)

- Internal Microphone
- Headset Microphone

Under pavucontrol, in the Input Devices tab the port has the following

- Internal Microphone (plugged in)
- Headset Microphone (plugged in)
- Microphone (unplugged)

Once I connect my headphones (it's a headphones + microphone combo jack), in pavucontrol the Microphone entry changes from *(unplugged)* to *(plugged in)* and becomes the selected value. When this happens I cannot hear anything, even though the output device is Headphones. I have to change the input Device to either Headset Microphone or Internal Microphone.

However, in all these combinations, the only time the microphone works is when it is set to Internal Microphone. In this case the laptop Microphone is used.

I have confirmed that there is no issue with my headphones.

And the output from `pactl list sources`

```
pactl list sources
Source #0
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 40000 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x604b118000 irq 170"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "02c8"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #1
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 7196 /  11% / -57.56 dB,   front-right: 7196 /  11% / -57.56 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 40000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3271 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3271 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x604b118000 irq 170"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "02c8"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900, available)
        analog-input-headphone-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700, not available)
        analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (priority: 8800, available)
    Active Port: analog-input-internal-mic
    Formats:
        pcm
```

I do hope someone can help with this, it's quite annoying that the headset mic does not work, because I can't type while on call unless I mute myself, which is not the most practical during meetings!

Thanks